# Delete specific documents after 7 days

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have made a TTL index on my Schema using:

```
Schema.index({ expire: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 604800 })
```

When I want documents to be deleted after the 7 days I use:

```
Schema.updateMany(query, { $set: { expire: Date.now() } })
```

Is this the correct way? Is there an easier way to delete specific documents after 7 days?
When I want a document to expire do I need to set the TTL index value to a date or could I use a different value?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a TTL index using (`expireAfterSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60` ). It will help you to automatically delete the documents.